# How to set "simple" password in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --username admin
```

After that it prompts for password and when I enter "admin" I got the following message:

> This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
>   This password is too common.

I haven't seen this on earlier versions of Django.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tune your [`AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS) setting by removing the `django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator` out there.

[Password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation) is a new feature introduced in Django 1.9.

Comment: Is it possible to remove this settings only for "superuser"? For simplicity of testing

Comment: You could (and should, IMHO) have different settings for local developement and production. If you already do, then it's rather easy, just empty the `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` in your dev settings.

Answer (score 4):

Django 1.9 introduced password validators so this is what you're seeing, you can disable them in the settings.py but its not a good idea to do so.

You should heed its advice and set a stronger password!

See the documentation on [Password Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation)

If you *do* want to get around this, you can by doing it in a shell (or by writing your own [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/)) but I **do not** recommend this (read above)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser('name', 'email', 'password')
```

Comment: But I find that `asdf` is an amazing password for development purposes which is precisely my reason for disabling it. I agree that the validators should be enabled for production, but for development (specifically my personal, local DB)? There is no reason.

Comment: Still unclear, how to skip validation in shell.

python manage.py changepassword --help

does not have such switches